# Django ModelForms: Trying to save a form with a foreign key

Tags: django

Django will just go to the else condition.

here's the code:

## models.py

```
class StakeholderProfile(models.Model):
    types = models.ForeignKey(Stakeholder)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50)
```

## forms.py

```
class SPForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StakeholderProfile
        exclude = ('key_contact_person',)
```

## views.py

```
def profile(request):
    stakeholderprofile = StakeholderProfile.objects.all()

    if  request.method == 'POST':
        form = SPForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        form = SPForm()
    return render_to_response('profile.html',{'form':form,'sp':stakeholderprofile})
```

I really need your help sir/maam.

Comment: When does Django "go to the else condition"? Did you ensure that you are making a `POST` request?

Comment: You are excluding a field `key_contact_person` that does not exist in the `StakeholderProfile` model

Comment: Can you please post your template/form snippet also? Are you using any inlines?

Answer (score 0):

You are excluding a field that doesn't exist in StakeHolderProfile.
Also be sure you added `method='POST'` in your form tag.